# Getting the value of jSF r:inputRichText component when page executed in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsf, richtextbox, getter

**code**

```
<r:inputRichText width="702" height="200" id="commentVal"></r:inputRichText>
```

**Getter Method**

```
getCommentVal().getValue().toString();
```

*Problem Statement*

When I run the page having `r:inputRichText` in **Mozilla Firefox or in IE** getter method of the `r:inputRichText` will return it's content but same method will return empty when it is executed in chrome browser.

Please help me to rectify this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: At least suggest alternative component for <r:inputRichText> that works well in chrome browser.